Flutter(Serving index.html file from a different subdomain) - SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History'
A history state object with URL 'https://app.foo.com/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'https://test.foo.com' and URL 'https://test.foo.com/'.
I am using flutter to build web app and have a goal to serve the root html file from where the backend is hosted (https://app.foo.com) and I'd want to host the rest of the assets (js, images, css etc.) from a CDN.
Initially I added the base to the index.html file to be "https://app.foo.com" with which i expect all the asset path would be based out of the url and it works. But as soon as i open the url, it gives me the error
SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'https://app.foo.com/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'https://test.foo.com' and URL 'https://test.foo.com/'.
In the example above, https://app.foo.com is my cdn url and test.foo.com is the host for index.html file.
I tried setting the base target to different values.
I tried playing around with the flutter app initialization
_flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
    assetBase: "https://app.foo.com",
    serviceWorker: {
      serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
    },
    onEntrypointLoaded: function(engineInitializer) {
      engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function(appRunner) {
        appRunner.runApp();
      });
    }
  });

I am expecting this to work as same as it works when the index.html file is served from where the assets are served.
The issue seems to come due to the navigation happening from a different origin. Not sure..
